# Words with friends style listview

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an android game which loads a list of 'games' the user has against his friends. Similar to the "game words with friends"

[image]

To recreate this type of view, I originally used a listview, but because there different elements, ie, games, sections (their move - your move) etc, I don't think I can do this kind of layout with purely a listview?

Has anyone done something similar? I might just use a scroll view and build up the layout dynamically, but my worry is that if a user has many games, performance will suffer.

Can anyone advise?

Comment: Sorry, the issue is not with creating the list view items for the games. What I'm asking is how to display what looks like 2 listviews. Ie, one listview for your games and another listview for their games

Comment: Looks like (headers, containing only "Their Move" or "Your Move"), or behaves like (scrolling them separately?)?

Comment: That's the thing the whole view scrolls as one element. I wonder if they are just using two separate tablelayouts?

Comment: Then you should consider my answer. The getView() method receives rendered position, so that you can check whether it is the header one (I guess 1st and 5th in your case), and set custom instructions for it's rendering (If I understood you correctly).

Comment: according to your tablelayouts mentioning: I personally think that listview is ok for that sort of things, if it really is a list (and it seems to me so, as of picture you posted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override the `getView()` method in your listview adapter.
It's responsible for displaying each item's layout. You will be able to do there something like:

```
if(position == YOUR_MOVE_POSITION) {

     // here hide ordinary elements, and set the ones you need to be visible
}
```

Look here for detailed info: [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)

**Example: (how I see the solution)**

This method is in your adapter class (which you use to populate the `ListView`, so you need to Override it with the code like below:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  final View v;

  if(position == 1) {  // here come instructions for 'header' no.1
    v = createViewFromResource(position, convertView, parent, mResource);

    // the widget you want to show in header:
    ImageView yourMoveImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.your_move);

    // and here come widgets you don't want to show in headers:
    ImageView otherWidget = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.other_widget);

    // then you set the visibility:
    yourMoveImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);    // here is the key
    otherWidget.setVisibility(View.GONE);       // it may also be View.INVISIBLE (look up the official docs for details)   


  } else {

    if(position == 5){  // here come instructions for 'header' no.1


      v = createViewFromResource(position, convertView, parent, mResource);

      // the widget you want to show in header:
      ImageView theirMoveImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.their_move);

      // and here come widgets you don't want to show in headers:
      ImageView otherWidget = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.other_widget); 

      // then you set the visibility:
      yourMoveImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);    // here is the key
      otherWidget.setVisibility(View.GONE);       // it may also be View.INVISIBLE (look up the official docs for details)   

    } else {

      // if it is the regular item, just show it as desribed in your XML:
      v = createViewFromResource(position, convertView, parent, mResource);
    }
  }

  return v;
}
```

Comment: Replied to my own question with some clarification

Comment: Is it possible to style each row 1st and 5th so differently as in the screenshot above to give the appearance of a header?

Comment: Yes, and this is exactly what you need. I've provided my answer with some sample code.

Comment: In fact, I've just googled a bit, and there are some ready solutions, but they do basically the same things: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/

Comment: Thanks again, for the useful tutorials :-)